# Select by default all options in <select>

Tags: javascript, php, html, drupal, html-select

I need when i charge the html, select by default all options by the option list: 
this is part of my code in .inc

```
drupal_add_js(
            "
            var projects='$projectsEncode';
            var narrativeList='$narrativeListEncode';
            var outputs='$outputsEncode';
            var topoNetwork='$topologicalNetworkEncode';
            var datasetUuid='$datasetUuid';
            var narrativeCount='$narrativeCount';
            var footprintNid='$footprintLayersEncode';
            ",
            'inline'
        );
```

this is part of my code in the .js

```
var narratives = JSON.parse(narrativeList);
var narrativeDropdown = $("#narrativeMode");
narratives.forEach(function (narrative) {
narrativeDropdown.append('<option value=' + narrative.nid + '> 
 Narrativa ' + narrative.name + '</option>');
  });
var elements = document.getElementById("narrativeMode").options;
console.log("Elementos cargados:",elements)
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
 elements[i].selected= true;

}
```

and this is the html.

```
<select class="mi-selector custom-select" multiple='multiple' data-style="form-control" data-live-search="true" title="-- Seleccione mínimo 1--" id="narrativeMode">

        </select>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the values, not setting them:

```
elements[i].selected == true;
```

Use:

```
elements[i].selected = true;
```

Working example:

```js
var narrativeDropdown = $("#narrativeMode");
var elements = document.getElementById("narrativeMode").options;
console.log("Elementos cargados:", elements)
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].selected = true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="mi-selector custom-select" multiple='multiple' data-style="form-control" data-live-search="true" title="-- Seleccione mínimo 1--" id="narrativeMode">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

**Update**

You can add `selected` to the option elements when creating them:

```
narrativeDropdown.append('<option value=' + narrative.nid + ' selected> 
  Narrativa ' + narrative.name + '</option>');
});
```

By doing this you don't have to loop over the options again, so you can remove this loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
  elements[i].selected= true;
}
```

Comment: my option  list is dinamic, i update the post with new code fragment in .inc

Comment: The main point of my answer is to use single `=` instead of double.

Answer (score 0):

Your code don't work because you are comparing `selected` instead of attributing.

Change this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
  elements[i].selected== true; // Note the use of == here
}
```

to this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
  elements[i].selected = true; // Note the use of single = here
}
```

Comment: i change the "==" by "=", but not fix